# Node.js best way to handle promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have code that looks like this in my controller.

```
const Users = require("../models/users");    

class UserController() {
    getUserById(req, res) {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const users = new Users();
        const userData = users.getUserById(uid).then(function(result) {
            //Do other logic here that depends on db result
            return res.status(200).json({status:"success", user: result});
        });
    }
}
```

My question is, what's the difference between that and the following, and which is the better practice?

```
const Users = require("../models/users");    

class UserController() {
    async getUserById(req, res) {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const users = new Users();
        const userData = await users.getUserById(uid);
        return res.status(200).json({status:"success",user:userData});
    }
}
```

Comment: As you've written it there isn't one. Note that depending on your version of node an UnhandledPromiseRejection will kill your process. Suggest you add some error handling.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will add some error handling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second function call is using **async-await** feature of ES8, This makes our code appear as if it is **synchronous** and clean also, without doing **.then()** and callback within it. Both **fetch()** and **async-await** work on promise though.

**Aync-Await** is much more readable if I can put it this way. No call backs used here. It simply waits for the first API call to happen and only when the data arrives (or Promise is resolved) we fire another API call. For programmer itself life becomes little easy with Async-Await syntax.

For Error handling you will need `try{} catch{}` block in **Aync-await** but in case of **fetch()**, **.catch()** block handles API Errors for us.

Comment: Thanks your for answer! So I imagine that the second one is best practice? And would it not be weird to have pretty much every function in my controllers class be async since it would be waiting on database stuff from the model quite a bit?

Comment: Thank you for the resource and answer, I will check it out!